# How to click another macro while a macro is running?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code that will automatically refresh a website every 10 minutes. I have a Start and Stop button. Once the start button is clicked, the refreshing will start. The problem is I can't click the Stop button because a code is running.

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub Start()

    wksMain.Range("A5").Value = "start"

x:
    VBA.DoEvents

    If wksMain.Range("A5").Value = "stop" Then Exit Sub

        AppActivate "Kampala - Wikipedia"
        SendKeys "{F5}"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:10:00"))

    GoTo x

End Sub

Public Sub Stopper()
    wksMain.Range("A5").Value = "stop"
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a limitation of single thread application (which excel is). There are ways round it. You could have a modeless `Form` and have your code run on that. Then in your excel, you could have a button in the `Worksheet` for Stop and Start (which essentially updates `A5` column). The code in your `From` can than check this cell before refreshing the page. Also, rather than using `Goto`, please use a `Do..While` loop

Comment: Hi @Zac should I include a Start and Stop button in my form?

Comment: No. Have 1 button in your worksheet. Set initial caption to **Start**. When the user presses the button, change the button caption to **Stop**, update the value in cell `A5` to: `Start` and launch your form. Code in your form should check the value in cell `A5` before refresh action. Now when the use press **Stop** button, update cell value to **Stop**, change caption of the button to **Start**. You will have to be bit cleaver with your form code to possibly check the cell value every couple of seconds